# Selected Boot Device Failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04. When I installed Ubuntu, the installation went smoothly. But after booting up after a Windows 10 session I'm presented with "Selected boot device failed. Press return to continue." I'm taken to a screen where I can choose Ubuntu or Windows. How can I repair the boot manager? Here is the verbose read output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,3002,0001,2002,3001,3001,2001,2004
Boot0000* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)  
PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)/CDROM(1,0xbe5dc,0x1200)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,625a877a-bad7-4508-91d0-91c7815fe814,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...7................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,625a877a-bad7-4508-91d0-91c7815fe814,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)  
PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)/CDROM(1,0xbe5dc,0x1200)RC
Boot0004* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)/CDROM(1,0xbe5dc,0x1200)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

Comment: It sounds like your boot order settings have gotten messed up. Please type `sudo efibootmgr -v` in Ubuntu and *edit* your question to add that output. Please add four spaces to the start of each line of output to keep the formatting sane.

Comment: I decided to bite the bullet and reinstalled Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 no more boot issues.